# why cant my function keep a total amount of int values within file?

Tags: java

I am making a program that reads a file of mixed values (int and string), prints only the integer values and keeps a running total of the amount of integer values within the file. Everything is working except for my running total of integer values within a given file and i am very confused on why it keeps printing 0 when i know there are more then 0 integer values within the file.

Here is my code:

```
package davi0030_a03;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFile {
    private String fileName; // name of the file
    private int count = 0; // number of valid integers in the file
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 10; // the size of the array
    private Scanner inputStream = null;
    private int[] theArray = new int[MAX_SIZE];
    private boolean strangeInt = false;
    private int total = 0;

// constructor to set the file name

public MyFile(String theName) { // constructor to set the file name
    this.fileName = new String(theName);

    // you may or may not want to do other stuffs here
}

public void openFile() {
    System.out.println("opening file: " + fileName);
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/davi0030_a03/"
                + fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not found or could not be opened");

    }
}

// log a message on whether two ints in the file add to target
public void findPair(int target) {
    openFile();
    fileToArray();
    findStrangeInt();
    findTotal();


}
public void findTotal(){
    inputStream.reset();
    while(inputStream.hasNext()){
        if(inputStream.hasNextInt()){           
            total +=1;
        }
        inputStream.next();
    }
    System.out.println(total);

}

public void findStrangeInt() {
    inputStream.reset();
    while (inputStream.hasNext()) {

        try {

            Integer.parseInt(inputStream.next());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            strangeInt = true;
        }
    }
    if (strangeInt = true) {
        System.out.println("File contains an incorrectly written int");
    }
}

public void fileToArray() {
    inputStream.reset();
    while (inputStream.hasNext() && count < MAX_SIZE) {
        if (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
            theArray[count] = inputStream.nextInt();
            count++;
        }

    }

}

// print the content of the file
public void printFile() {
    openFile();
    inputStream.reset();
    System.out.println("Printing content of file " + fileName);
    while (inputStream.hasNext()) {

        try {

            int convert = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.next());
            System.out.println(convert);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("xxx");
        }
    }

}
```

}

content of file:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

13

14

a

b

d

Comment: Please show us the content of your input file.

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues beyond those you report here (opening streams multiple times, creating unnecessary new strings, work in constructors etc, checking `== true` in conditional, swallowing exceptions). Can I suggest heading over to codereview.stackexchange.com to get some pointers on how to improve it?

Comment: You have some problems in your code. the openFile() called by the constructor and also by findPair(). make your code more logical and close the unnecessary resources. my JVM almost stuck ...

Comment: so far i have fixed my program so that it only opens the file once. After the file has been opened the file contents are then stored within an array so that i can fiddle around with the array without having to scan through the file every time i want to do something. Thanks for all the help everyone and sorry for the messy code, it has since been updated :).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My solution below most likely solves the logic issue regarding your searching the file. However, I suggest you read some of the other comments the question has gotten. The IO handling here especially needs some improvement.

I believe your issue lies in your while statement. According to java documentation on the Scanner class,[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()), the method .hasNextInt() is returning based on the next element scanned. I think you are assuming it will return true as long as there are ints in the file. This is not the case. If the first thing the scanner hits is not an int, it is returning false and exiting your while loop. This would explain the returned 0, the value you initialize your variable 'total' to. I would suggest you do something like the following:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()){           
        total +=1;
    }
    scanner.next();
}
```

Comment: Added this to the code as well as fixing some IO handling but still getting a total output of 0.